# How do I save a webpage to the disk for later scraping using splinter library?

Tags: python, web-scraping, splinter

I have the following python code using splinter library for searching a specific term in a website:

```
from splinter import Browser
browser = Browser()

browser.visit("http://decs.bvs.br/cgi-bin/wxis1660.exe/decsserver/?IsisScript=../cgi-bin/decsserver/decsserver.xis&interface_language=p&previous_page=homepage&previous_task=NULL&task=start")
browser.choose('search_language','p')
browser.fill('search_exp','costas')
element = browser.find_by_name("consult_button")
element.click()
```

And it works, the firefox page opens the page with the results. However I have not found a way to save those results as a html file to disk in orde to scrape them for terms. How do you save the webpage to disk using splinter?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Has the answer helped to solve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

You can open a file for writing and write [`browser.html`](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/docs/browser.html#verifying-page-content-with-browser-html) to it:

```
with open('output.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(browser.html.encode('utf-8'))
```

---

Note that I don't see the legitimate reason why you need to save the html for post-scraping. `splinter` (as is `selenium`) is powerful in terms of locating elements. The library is not only for programmatic web-browsing, it can navigate, search, extract etc. See [Finding elements](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/docs/finding.html).